# Microsoft Forefront won't turn on

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I am at home with a work machine and cannot get Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 to turn on.

If I go to my `Start Menu` >> `All Programs` >> `Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection` I get its main screen. In the center of the screen is a big red button that reads *Turn on*. When I click it, the program hangs for about 45 seconds, and then gives me the following error message (code 0x800705b4):

[image: couldn't turn on real-time protection (timeout period expired)]

Is MFE a client-server application? If so, I am wondering if I am getting this because I am not VPNed in (and thus, can't connect to a server). If not, what does that error code mean? I searched for it but nothing really turned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forefront is designed to be run in an environment with a server in place; while there are ways of getting it to work otherwise, presumably yours isn't configured that way.  I would suggest trying again on the VPN.

Comment: VPNed in and still the same message. Any ideas? If I have a virus could it be blocking the MFE client from turning on?

Comment: It's possible.  Unfortunately I'm not super familiar with Forefront beyond the basics - I'd suggest talking to your sysadmin about this, frankly, because it may be a configuration problem they've seen before.